Azure YAML pipelines object as parameters read from file
I have a task template that is a PowerShell task that needs 3 parameters.
parameters:
    param1: ''
    param2: ''
    param3: ''

  steps:

    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: | [string[]] $SqlCmdVariables = "${{ parameters.param1 }}" -split "," | ForEach-Object { $_.trim() }
                  [string] $file = "${{ parameters.param2 }}/${{ parameters.param3 }}" -replace "/", "\"


I have a job template taht uses the task template like
jobs:
- deployment: DeploymentTest 

  pool:
    name: Default

  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
      
        - template: ../../Template/Step/runPowerShellDeployment.yml
          parameters:
            param1: 'dbName=DbNameEnvA secondDbName=AnotherDBInEnvA'
            param2: 'someScriptFile.sql'
            param3: 'InstanceA'

            
        - template: ../../Template/Step/runPowerShellDeployment.yml
          parameters:
            param1: 'dbName=DbTestNameEnvA secondDbName=AnotherTestDBInEnvA thirdDb=YetAnotherDbInEnvA'
            param2: 'someScriptFile.sql'
            param3: 'InstanceATest'
            
        - template: ../../Template/Step/runPowerShellDeployment.yml
          parameters:
            param1: 'dbName=DbCucumberTestNameEnvA secondDbName=AnotherCucumberTestDBInEnvA OtherParam=JustToShowThatParam1IsJustAString'
            param2: 'someScriptFile.sql'
            param3: 'InstanceACucumberTest'




What I would like to do is to use a loop for each environment and define the parameters in separate files (envA.yml, envB.yml, etc.). But I'm not sure about how to define the parameter values in the files and how to read it in the new template like here for param1, param2 and param3 :
EDIT: the same environment will have 3 to 5 times the template, each with different parameters values. That is why I would also need a loop at task level I think
parameters:
- name: environmentsToDeploy
  type: object
  default:
  - EnvironmentA
  - EnvironmentB


jobs:

- ${{ each value in parameters.environmentsToDeploy }}:
  - deployment: DeploymentTest 

    pool:
      name: Default

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
      
        steps:
            - template: ../../Template/Step/runPowerShellDeployment.yml
              parameters:
                param1: 
                param2: 
                param3: 

           - template: ../../Template/Step/runPowerShellDeployment.yml
              parameters:
                param1: 
                param2: 
                param3:

          - template: ../../Template/Step/runPowerShellDeployment.yml
              parameters:
                param1: 
                param2: 
                param3:



Parameters are expanded before the pipeline runs, but you define them in 3 yamls. Unless you use another pipeline to read the yamls, pass value to current one, then current pipeline can get the value for each loop. But it's more complicated. As @RuiJarimba showed below, you can use variable instead parameter.  You can also check doc: "Use variables if you need your values to be more widely available during your pipeline run."

You should loop your job not your task, A better way to achieve your goal, Just a sample to show the pattern:
azure-pipeline.yml
parameters:
- name: environmentsToDeploy
  type: object
  default:
  - EnvironmentA
  - EnvironmentB
  - EnvironmentC

jobs:

- ${{ each environment in parameters.environmentsToDeploy }}:
  - deployment: ${{ environment }}Deployment
    environment: ${{ environment }} 
    variables:
    - template: ${{ environment }}.yml 
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - template: 'template.yml'
            parameters:
              param1: $(param1)
              param2: $(param2)
              param3: $(param3)

template.yml
parameters:
- name: param1
  type: string
  default: ''

- name: param2
  type: string
  default: ''

- name: param3
  type: string
  default: ''

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "print ${{ parameters.param1 }}, ${{ parameters.param2 }}, ${{ parameters.param3 }} "


EnvironmentA.yml
variables:
- name: param1
  value: 'test1A'
- name: param2
  value: 'test2A'
- name: param3
  value: 'test3A'

EnvironmentB.yml
variables:
- name: param1
  value: 'test1B'
- name: param2
  value: 'test2B'
- name: param3
  value: 'test3B'

EnvironmentC.yml
variables:
- name: param1
  value: 'test1C'
- name: param2
  value: 'test2C'
- name: param3
  value: 'test3C'



Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. I figured out that I needed a job loop just before seeing your answer, perfect timing!

Would recommend looking at making these stages NOT jobs. Stages can be re ran as a group which is what I think you are going for in the case of a redeployment.

Variables can be set at the job level, but not at the task level - this means that if you want to run N scripts in the same job, each with 3 different values you'd have to create N*3 different variables - in your case, 3x3=9 distinct variables.
It's easier to have a separate job to deploy each environment instead:

Create one variables template for each environment, such as /pipelines/variables/prod-variables.yaml
Reference the variables template in the job and run the script for a specific environment (e.g. production)

Example
azure-pipeline.yaml
parameters:
- name: environments
  displayName: 'Environments to deploy to'
  type: object
  default:
  - test
  - qa
  - prod

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
  - ${{ each environment in parameters.environments }}:
    - job: ${{ environment }}
      displayName: 'Deploy to ${{ environment }}'
      variables:
        # reference the right variables template for each environment
        - template: /pipelines/variables/${{ environment }}-variables.yaml
      steps:
        - script: |
            echo "Param1: ${{ variables.param1 }}"
            echo "Param2: ${{ variables.param2 }}"
            echo "Param3: ${{ variables.param3 }}"
          displayName: 'Deploy to ${{ environment }}'

/pipelines/variables/test-variables.yaml
variables:
  param1: testValue1
  param2: testValue2
  param3: testValue3

/pipelines/variables/qa-variables.yaml
variables:
  param1: qaValue1
  param2: qaValue2
  param3: qaValue3

/pipelines/variables/qa-variables.yaml
variables:
  param1: prodValue1
  param2: prodValue2
  param3: prodValue3

Running the pipeline - one job is generated for each deployment:

